# Cannot deploy a cloudera manager image on Openshift

Tags: openshift, cloudera-manager

Sorry, I don't know if this is the right place to post this ...

I m trying to do a simple spark application using cloudera manager.

But I just can't, Every Image I try to deploy to the docker hub is failing (I can deploy other images but not the cloudera manager ones).

If you have any tip, I d be grateful.

thanks.

EDIT 1 :

```
    [openshift@acs-test-master-0 ~]$ oc new-app cloudera/quickstart
    --> Found Docker image 2cda829 (14 months old) from Docker Hub for "cloudera/quickstart"

        * An image stream will be created as "quickstart:latest" that will track this image
        * This image will be deployed in deployment config "quickstart"
        * The image does not expose any ports - if you want to load balance or send traffic to this component
          you will need to create a service with 'expose dc/quickstart --port=[port]' later
        * WARNING: Image "cloudera/quickstart" runs as the 'root' user which may not be permitted by your cluster administrator

    --> Creating resources ...
        imagestream "quickstart" created
        deploymentconfig "quickstart" created
    --> Success
        Run 'oc status' to view your app.

    [openshift@acs-test-master-0 ~]$ oc status
    In project hkouki on server https://10.64.178.245:8443

    dc/quickstart deploys istag/quickstart:latest
      deployment #1 running for 9 seconds - 1 pod

    3 warnings identified, use 'oc status -v' to see details.
    [openshift@acs-test-master-0 ~]$ oc status -v
    In project hkouki on server https://10.64.178.245:8443

    dc/quickstart deploys istag/quickstart:latest
      deployment #1 running for 17 seconds - 1 pod

    Warnings:
      * pod/quickstart-1-deploy has no liveness probe to verify pods are still running.
        try: oc set probe pod/quickstart-1-deploy --liveness ...
      * dc/quickstart has no readiness probe to verify pods are ready to accept traffic or ensure deployment is successful.
        try: oc set probe dc/quickstart --readiness ...
      * dc/quickstart has no liveness probe to verify pods are still running.
        try: oc set probe dc/quickstart --liveness ...

    View details with 'oc describe <resource>/<name>' or list everything with 'oc get all'.

[openshift@acs-test-master-0 ~]$ oc get events
LASTSEEN   FIRSTSEEN   COUNT     NAME                  KIND      SUBOBJECT                     TYPE      REASON       SOURCE                    MESSAGE
11m        11m         1         quickstart-1-deploy   Pod                                     Normal    Scheduled    {default-scheduler }      Successfully assigned quickstart-1-deploy to 192.168.232.2
11m        11m         1         quickstart-1-deploy   Pod       spec.containers{deployment}   Normal    Pulled       {kubelet 192.168.232.2}   Container image "openshift3/ose-deployer:v3.4.0.39" already present on machine
11m        11m         1         quickstart-1-deploy   Pod       spec.containers{deployment}   Normal    Created      {kubelet 192.168.232.2}   Created container with docker id b68834b1d135; Security:[seccomp=unconfined]
11m        11m         1         quickstart-1-deploy   Pod       spec.containers{deployment}   Normal    Started      {kubelet 192.168.232.2}   Started container with docker id b68834b1d135
1m         1m          1         quickstart-1-deploy   Pod       spec.containers{deployment}   Normal    Killing      {kubelet 192.168.232.2}   Killing container with docker id b68834b1d135: Need to kill pod.
11m        11m         1         quickstart-1-pbbtt    Pod                                     Normal    Scheduled    {default-scheduler }      Successfully assigned quickstart-1-pbbtt to 192.168.232.2
1m         11m         34        quickstart-1-pbbtt    Pod       spec.containers{quickstart}   Normal    Pulling      {kubelet 192.168.232.2}   pulling image "cloudera/quickstart@sha256:f91bee4cdfa2c92ea3652929a22f729d4d13fc838b00f120e630f91c941acb63"
1m         11m         34        quickstart-1-pbbtt    Pod       spec.containers{quickstart}   Normal    Pulled       {kubelet 192.168.232.2}   Successfully pulled image "cloudera/quickstart@sha256:f91bee4cdfa2c92ea3652929a22f729d4d13fc838b00f120e630f91c941acb63"
1m         11m         34        quickstart-1-pbbtt    Pod       spec.containers{quickstart}   Warning   Failed       {kubelet 192.168.232.2}   Failed to create docker container "quickstart" of pod "quickstart-1-pbbtt_hkouki(ead5ca64-4ce6-11e7-9cd6-fa163ec8e6c3)" with error: Error response from daemon: {"message":"No command specified"}
    1m         11m         34        quickstart-1-pbbtt    Pod                                     Warning   FailedSync   {kubelet 192.168.232.2}   Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "quickstart" with RunContainerError: "runContainer: Error response from daemon: {\"message\":\"No command specified\"}"

    11m       11m       1         quickstart-1   ReplicationController             Normal    SuccessfulCreate              {replication-controller }        Created pod: quickstart-1-pbbtt
    1m        1m        1         quickstart-1   ReplicationController             Normal    SuccessfulDelete              {replication-controller }        Deleted pod: quickstart-1-pbbtt
    11m       11m       1         quickstart     DeploymentConfig                  Normal    DeploymentCreated             {deploymentconfig-controller }   Created new replication controller "quickstart-1" for version 1
    1m        1m        1         quickstart     DeploymentConfig                  Normal    ReplicationControllerScaled   {deploymentconfig-controller }   Scaled replication controller "quickstart-1" from 1 to 0
    [openshift@acs-test-master-0 ~]$ oc get all
    NAME            DOCKER REPO                             TAGS      UPDATED
    is/quickstart   172.30.228.225:5000/hkouki/quickstart   latest    7 minutes ago

    NAME            REVISION   DESIRED   CURRENT   TRIGGERED BY
    dc/quickstart   1          1         1         config,image(quickstart:latest)

    NAME              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
    rc/quickstart-1   1         1         0         7m

    NAME                     READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
    po/quickstart-1-deploy   1/1       Running             0          7m
    po/quickstart-1-pbbtt    0/1       RunContainerError   0          7m
```

I also notice something, it might be nothing but I will explain it : 
To have external access to some services, I set the type of the service to NodePort or LoadBalancer and connect to the node hosting the service on the port openshift gave me. This even helped me get some images to work. But I dont really understand why.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific pls? Which OpenShift version? What image? What is the error message you see?

Comment: If OpenShift 3, do be aware that many images on Docker Hub require you to run the image as ``root``. Those images will not work in a hosting environment which enforces restrictions that images not run as ``root``. This is the usual cause of arbitrary images from Docker Hub not working. The error messages from pod when starting up would confirm whether this is the issue.

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas could you please check the edit, I tried to add every details I could think of.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton could you please check the edit, I tried to add every details I could think of.

Comment: Use the ``oc logs`` command on the pod to find out how it is failing on startup. Eg. ``oc logs po/quickstart-1-pbbtt``.

Comment: According to https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudera/quickstart/ they required a privileged container, likely as well as ``root`` execution. You don't get that by default in OpenShift and need admin rights to do so, so not possible in OpenShift Online if you were using that.